# Setting UITableViewCell height based on UITableViewHeight BEFORE drawing

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

iOS 13 (but seems to hold true in iOS 10.3, also).

I'm having a very hard time getting the final height of a view in a complex view hierarchy before anything is drawn to the screen. I have a UIPageViewControl with a series of custom UIViewController. One of the subviews in that is a table view, and I want to adjust the cell height based on the table view's height so that I have an integral number of cells showing.

Unfortunately, the final height of the table view is not determined, it seems, until after all hooks have been exhausted. I've tried all of the following: `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWill/DidAppear()`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, `layoutSubviews()` and `didMoveToWindow()` (on the table view and the root view). I've tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` in each of the above.

In the end, well after `didMoveToWindow()` (which comes *after* `viewDidAppear`, annoyingly), `layoutSubviews()` gets called a couple more times, and it’s only in those last two calls that the view has its final height. At this point it’s not possible to set the cell height and reload the table view without it visibly changing on-screen.

There seems to be no way to accomplish this.

Am I missing something? I guess I can try UICollectionView instead.

Comment: Hmm... quick test, using a table view as a subview of one of the page view controllers, no problems getting the laid-out height of the table view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Are you designing your pages in Storyboard, or via code-only? And when you say you *"want to adjust the cell height based on the table view's height so that I have an integral number of cells showing"* -- how are you trying to calculate that? Maybe that's where the issue is? Can you put together a [mre]?

Comment: I did end up doing the work to put together a minimal example, and sent it along with a bug report to Apple. PageViewController gets a proper `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but the sub view controllers don't.

Comment: Rick... I put together a simple page view controller project. Two pages have table views. One uses exactly 6 rows, the other uses a minimum height for the rows. See if it is what you were going for: https://github.com/DonMag/TableInPageView